# Convexity of product of two given functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a convex function of $x$ in a given positive interval. Also assume $f(x)\geq 0$ everywhere in that interval. Is the function $g(x)=xf(x)$ convex in that interval?. Is it possible that $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing.

Comment: To address the last part of your Question, can $g(x)$ be *monotone*, yes, this is possible for $g(x) = xf(x)$ of the form you specify.  For example, if $f(x)= x^2$ then $g(x) = x^3$ is monotone increasing on every (positive) interval.  But perhaps you have another "possibility" in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N0. Let $f\colon(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be defined by $f(x)=x^{-p}$, $0<p<1$. $f$ is convex, since
$$
f''(x)=-p(p-1)x^{p-2}>0\quad\forall x>0.
$$
Howevwe
$$
x\,f(x)=x^{1-p}
$$
is concave.

Comment: does this mean that nothing can be said about the nature of $g(x)$ in general ?

Comment: @dineshdileep Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I request you to go through this question I am struggling with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654817/convexity-of-a-complicated-function

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=1-x$. This function is convex. But, $g(x)=x-x^2$, which is not convex. To get a monotonically increasing $g$, take $f(x)=1$. To get a monotonically decreasing $g$, take $f:[1,2]\to\mathbb R$, defined by $f(x)=\frac{2-x}x$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. +1

Comment: I request you to go through this question I am struggling with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654817/convexity-of-a-complicated-function